# where should i put the code of sweetalert to confirm delete?

Tags: laravel, sweetalert2

this is my code on
 **index.blade.php**

```
{{ Form :: open  (['method'=>'DELETE', 'route'=>['assistants.destroy', $value -> id , 'style'=> 'Display']])}}

                <button  type="submit" style="display: inline;" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" ><i class=" glyphicon glyphicon-trash">

                    </i>
                </button>
                {{ Form::close() }}
```

Comment: Swal.fire({
  title: 'Are you sure?',
  text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
  type: 'warning',
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
  cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
  confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
}).then((result) => {
  if (result.value) {
    Swal.fire(
      'Deleted!',
      'Your file has been deleted.',
      'success'
    )
  }
})    this is the code of sweetalert

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using laravel 5.5+ for your project then you can do something like this :

Add a ID to your form :

```
{!! Form::open(['method'=>'DELETE', 'route'=>['assistants.destroy', $value -> id , 'style'=> 'Display', 'id' => 'MyDeleteForm']]) !!}
<button  type="submit" style="display: inline;" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
    <i class=" glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
</button>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

and then you can use this script to process your request using ajax or so :

```
var MyDeleteForm = $('#MyDeleteForm');
MyDeleteForm.submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    Swal.fire({ 
        title: 'Are you sure?', 
        text: "You won't be able to revert this!", 
        type: 'warning', 
        showCancelButton: true, 
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6', 
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33', 
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!' 
    }).then((result) => { 
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            success: function(data) {
                Swal.fire( 'Deleted!', 'Your file has been deleted.', 'success' ) 
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I hope this will help you.